# Any benefit in Using ONLINE index when creating a new non-clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a huge heap table (nearly 27 million records) with few columns of data type nvarchar(max). This is a log table, hence it is confirmed that there will not be any "UPDATE" statements running. There are only a bunch of INSERT and SELECT statements running all the time.

Now in order to improve "SELECT" performance, I am planning to create a Non-Clustered index whose key includes columns of the above table of Data type INT & Date.

Now I am just wondering will there be any merit in building this index ONLINE?

Comment: It can require more disk space during the operation. Otherwise no.

Comment: @plaidDK - So you meant, offline index is the way to go in this case? Won't it block inserts?

Comment: Actually, there is a huge benefit and space has nothing to do with it. ONLINE creates the new index pages on the side (which is probably why @plaidDK is confused about the size). When that finishes, it replaces the original pages resulting in almost no interruption. The old pages are deleted so there's no extra space used. Otherwise queries that needed the index would have to block until the index was created. You **DO** want online rebuild if you have a large table and don't want downtime

Comment: Another benefit for programmers/DBAs is that you *don't* have to tell your business users they have to stop working while you apply a change. Which means you don't have to wait for people to leave for the day before rebuilding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But its only if he doesnt want downtime yes. And yes i makes an exclusive lock on your table. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql#online-option

Comment: @plaidDK I suspect you are confused about what ONLINE is, what it does and how it's doesn't affect how the index is stored

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know exactly what it does. Read the document i posted.

Comment: The underlying table cannot be altered, truncated, or dropped while an online index operation is in process.

@PanagiotisKanavos I dont disagree with you. I justed stated the obvious of what it can require to build an online index. On his requirements it will be an ONLINE index which makes sense as you write. Additional temporary disk space is required during the index operation.

Online operations can be performed on partitioned indexes and indexes that contain persisted computed columns, or included columns.

Comment: @plaidDK before you pick a fight with a SQL Server MVP ... Please read the doc you posted. Also read the articles by SQL Server MVPs like Brent Ozar, Aaarob Bertrand, Itzik ben-Gan. And do take advantage of the 3 month free access to Pluralsight courses, through the free Visual Studio Dev Essentials progam.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont disagree with you? But even though you have some fancy title from being active in forums. You cannot deny the fact that it can require additonal disk place during the index operation.

Comment: @plaidDK if you don't get to manage the databases, you don't appreciate the importance of online operations. Don't say they aren't important though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Depends on your needs. I my self tend to use ONLINE = ON. But on rare occations i put them off, when i want the exclusive locks. And yes, that happens.